# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in

Tags: attributes

I am trying to get custom attribute value in frontend

I am trying below code in view.phtml , its working fine.

when i used the same code in other .phtml file its giving error :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in**

```
<?php 

$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
?>
```

Comment: this question is not clear add more information and `Mage::registry('current_product')` is not work out side the view.phtml file.

Comment: as you said , i replaced $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();  than 

we gave attributes value as "yes", but its displaying "NO"

Comment: it is yes and no dropdown?

Comment: yes, you are right...

Comment: there values are 1 and zero `if($_product->getData('cod_available')) { echo 'available'; }` this will be your condition.

Comment: i replaced this code : if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
} code by your code , now its displaying blank....

Comment: check your attribute value in product data
`echo '<pre>'; print_r($_product->getData());`
`if($_product->getCodAvailable())) { echo 'available'; }`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9c1cd5 i am getting data as like this.....

Comment: this is not complete image..

Comment: no, but i am getting complete data.....

Comment: this the cod_available listed there?

Comment: no, its not there.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32717/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code from:

```
<?php 

$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
?>
```

To:

view.phtml

```
<?php 
$currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
if($currentProduct) {
    $attribute = $currentProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
    if ($attribute) {
        echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    }
}
?>
```

other .phtml (But must be available getproduct() function in block file)

```
<?php 

$product = $this->getProduct();
if($product->getId()) {
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
    if ($attribute) {
        echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: its giving blank .... yes or no both are not displaying....

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: but  other .phtml  file use which block? are you added code in child block or main block?

Comment: i am displying quantity, price in same page. that means getproduct() function in block file is present?

Comment: try this code :<?php 

$product = $this->getProduct();
if($product->getId()) {
    $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
    if ($attribute) {
        echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    }
}
?>

Comment: its giving blank .... yes or no both are not displaying

Comment: cod_available attribute text or drop down?

Comment: its dropdown......

Comment: Multi select or single?

Comment: single one........

Comment: try this : <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getCodVvailable(), 'cod_available') ?> ;

Comment: please check here : http://prntscr.com/9c1j3a

Comment: or check your attribute is : Visible on Product View Page on Front-end : Yes OR No in admin end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32718/discussion-between-abdul-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
     $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
if($_product->getData('cod_available')) { echo 'available'; }
?>
```

Comment: @Qaisar Satti Thanks for your support boss as always.... , +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

If you using this code for product details page, please try:

> $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
>   $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

Comment: Product view page, its working fine. i need for other pages

Answer (score 1):

> when i used the same code in other .phtml file its giving error :
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in

```
Mage::registry('current_product')
```

Give Product object only on product page.your have used same code in other non-product page that's why it gives error.

Comment: what code i have to replace now...

Comment: on which page you want this ? do you get product id on that page ?

Comment: if you are getting product id then use Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

Comment: this code worked for price : <input type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>

Comment: i am trying the same code.....

Comment: i say on which page ????

Comment: we are using an extension  : we are displaying list of product information there. myproductlist.phtml page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32715/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-baby-in-magento).